# What is the best way to avoid "system out of memory" in node.js?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, v8

I am working on a project which need's to handle many ten's of thousands of active socket concurrent connections. Now been looking at the memory usage and the V8 engine, I am using Node.js v0.10.19 (Stable)

I can't afford for **"system out of memory"** event to happen. So currently working on running up to 15 node instances each limited to 1GB of RAM on a single server with plenty of RAM to operate with that & with quad core xeon processors and a load balancer to organise the load across all the instances.

So, is there a way to store socket connections outside the V8 Heap stack like in buffers or some other way so to reduce the Node.js memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally since you're keeping many thousands or tens of thousands of connections open you will be incurring a memory cost by doing so.

Here's what I would ask:

Are you adding things to an array or an object that is filling up?

Are you instantiating heavy modules for each open connection?

Can you run a profiler to see what is doing what? (People do rave about that DTrace.)

Would it be possible to poll at an interval for what you want instead of keeping web sockets open?

Something else you can try if you can't run a profiler is logging the status of the app as it runs so you can analyze the problem. It's an oldschool technique but you can log each time a function is ending and see what the current memory usage is. That might also chew up some memory but if you find the problem that way, great.

Checking the memory usage is done via the Process module:

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage

Good luck and please let me know what you find out. I'm curious to see how you solve that very challenging problem.